# C# WinForms: System.InvalidCastException only from Timer.ElapsedEventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have created a C# WinForms project with a webbrowser and separate controls to click certain buttons within the webbrowser, this all works fine so far. However, one of these buttons is supposed to be clicked at regular intervals (I chose 20 seconds for debugging). I try to click it with a System.Timers.Timer which fires at the .Elapsed event.

```
webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("link_logout").InvokeMember("click");
```

Whenever the button is supposed to be clicked (i.e. this line is in the ElapsedEventHandler) I get a System.InvalidCastException at exactly this line. The same happens when I try to click other buttons or fill a text field.

The strange thing is that the clicking of the button or filling the text field works fine when I do it witihin a Button_Click event.

The problem is obviously not that the html element isn't there, I get the same exception in an if clause, in the line if (element!=null).

Below is some more of my code:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(20 * 1000);

SomeMethodAtTheStart()
{
   t.Start();
   t.AutoReset = true;
   t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("link_logout").InvokeMember("click");
}

private void tsmiConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("link_logout").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What I normally do is to create a separate method when I need to run button coded from application.  So all I have in the button click is a call to a new method.  Then call the new method from the timer_elapse instead of the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S2)

> Unlike the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, the System.Timers.Timer class will, by default, call your timer event handler on a worker thread obtained from the common language runtime (CLR) thread pool. **This means that the code inside your Elapsed event handler must conform to a golden rule of Win32 programming: an instance of a control should never be accessed from any thread other than the thread that was used to instantiate it.**

Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead.

Edit: as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395623/invalidcastexception-when-using-webbrowser-and-threads-in-c-sharp#31395702) to the question [InvalidCastException when using webbrowser and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395623/invalidcastexception-when-using-webbrowser-and-threads-in-c-sharp)

> The WebBrowser doesn't like being accessed from other threads.

Comment: How is that related to `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: @SeM [_"The WebBrowser doesn't like being accessed from other threads."_ - InvalidCastException when using webbrowser and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395623/invalidcastexception-when-using-webbrowser-and-threads-in-c-sharp#31395702)

Comment: please update your answer or mark question as duplicate.

Comment: @SeM ok updated answer. I'm reluctant to mark this question as a dupe as this solution - using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of  `System.Timers.Timer` - is better **in this particular case** than the accepted answer in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I was going crazy because I couldn't understand what's going wrong